# Unable to filter my dataset via where statement in sas

Tags: dataframe, filter, sas, where-clause

I have the following dataset with 3 initial variables:
[image]

I have applied the following code to my data set to have months and quarter variables:

```
Data Example;
set Example;
month = put(date,monname8.);
quarter = QTR(date);
run;
```

I have then the following output(part of my table which have more than 30000 observations):
[image]

Then I want to filter for all observations with month = "June", I used the following code to do this :

```
Data Example;
set Example;
where month = "June";
run;
```

Then the output returns me a blank table with no observation at all:
[image]

I have tried with other variables such as country and quarter, they both works (returns me with the desired observations) with where statement. Only with the month variable it returns me with blank table.

Could anyone help me with this issue ?

Thank you!

Comment: Leading spaces in character string will be invisible looking at the data that way. Either print it to standard listing output or print it using the $QUOTE format to make the leading spaces appear in listing or l og.

Answer (score 2):

First, check if there are not any blank spaces in your code (e.g. " June" instead of "June"). Second, make sure to avoid blank spaces before and after month names:

```
WHERE strip(month) = "June";
```

If neither of them work, make sure there is "June" in your data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply

Comment: TRIM() will only remove trailing spaces, and those are ignored already.  You need LEFT() or STRIP() to remove leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tom, you are right. I will update my answer. I guess strip() is better because remove both left and trailing spaces, right

Answer (score 2):

Use the -l alignment option in PUT otherwise it adds spaces for padding.

```
month = put(date, monname8.  -l);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it works well with your code